# Why are the images being nested within my option elements not being displayed?

Tags: javascript, html, image

Strangely enough, when I use a div element as a parent and then nest other divs within it, the images are displayed. When I click on inspect I can see that the images are there. The console doesn't through an error, so I really don't know where I might have gone wrong

```js
const url = "https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all";
const select = document.querySelector("select");

fetch(url)
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => data.forEach(countryApp))

function countryApp(myData) {
  let option = document.createElement("option");
  let ctn = document.createTextNode(myData.name);
  option.appendChild(ctn);
  let img = document.createElement("img");
  img.setAttribute("src", myData.flag);
  img.setAttribute("alt", "country flag");
  img.setAttribute("width", 20);
  img.setAttribute("height", 20);
  option.appendChild(img);
  select.appendChild(option)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Practise App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <select class="" name=""></select>
    <script src="index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. That's what I thought, but I wasn't sure

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you can't put an image in the `option` using HTML only. However, instead of using an HTML tag to achieve this, you can get the result via CSS.

Adding

`<option style="background-image: url(path_to_the_image.format)>Some Option</option>`

Will help you. However, it needs to be tested on how it works with different browsers.